# R: Iterate over column with conditional index

Tags: r, loops

I have data from another program with poor formatting where each company's name is given once as a header, but then `NA` for each subsequent record.

```
company invoice  item
<chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
A            NA    NA
NA            1     5
NA            1     3
B            NA    NA
NA            2     2
C            NA    NA
NA            3     4
NA            4     7
NA            4     6
NA            5     8
```

I want to iterate through `company` replacing the `NA` values for each company with their name:

```
company invoice  item
<chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
A            NA    NA
A             1     5
A             1     3
B            NA    NA
B             2     2
C            NA    NA
C             3     4
C             4     7
C             4     6
C             5     8
```

Because the first instance of each company's name is correct, it made sense to me to use the index of `company[[i - 1]]` for each instance of `NA`. So, I was trying to iterate through the indexes with variations on the following:

```
df$company <- for (i in seq_along(df$company)) {
  if (is.na(df$company[[i]]) == TRUE) {
    df$company[[i]] = df$company[[i - 1]]
  } else {
    df$company[[i]] = df$company[[i]]
  }
}
```

Either it returns the `df` with `company` missing, or it returns `NULL`.  What do I need to change to get the result I want?

Comment: `tidyr::fill(df, company)`

Comment: Thanks!  Wasn't aware of `fill()`.